# unity --version > ImportError: No module named glib

Tags: unity, glib

When I execute the command **unity --version** as shown below, I am getting an error.

The Version is Ubuntu 15.10

```
alex@xc1706:~$ unity --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/unity", line 21, in <module>
    import glib
ImportError: No module named glib
```

Any Idea, why this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
sudo apt-get install python-gobject
```